# Effects of Grading on Students' Beliefs About Productivity

Tags: learning, reference-request, motivation

For lack of a teaching stackexchange, I hope this is a suitable place to ask:

I've encountered a number of adult individuals who feel bad if they're not "being productive" or are "producing low quality work" and I wonder if these feelings are exacerbated by having been in the grading-focused environment of schools. I imagine this being very hard to do formal research on (perhaps by looking at students' grades or exposure to messages about the importance of getting good grades or comparing with home-schooled students), but are there any studies or theoretical works on the effects of grading on beliefs about productivity?